# Make view wide as much as possible without cutting other view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I have two views (A and B) in a constraintLayout. I want to constraint A & B to the left/start of parent but I want A to be as wide as possible without cutting part of B (should be shown fully) to the right of A. If A is too wide, it should wrap to next line so that B can be shown fully. This is what I have tried so far but A seems to have taken fixed width leaving empty space between itself and B.

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        tools:text="Iceland A text"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/b"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:id="@+id/a"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:textColor="@color/tcBlack"
        tools:text="500 Items"
        android:id="@+id/b"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/a"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/a"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/a"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: As far as I understand from your question. You can set view B's right constraint to parent's right with making the width is wrap_content. Then you can set view A's left constraint to parent's left and right constraint to view B's left with making the width is match_constraint.

Comment: I have tried that but its looks same as I have above. A still seems to take a fixed width. If you have been able to make it work, please share your xml with me and I will mark your answer.

Comment: Can you share a picture of phone/emulator screen? I wonder how it looks like

Comment: from just text i did't quite understand what you want , can you share some sketch of what you want done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following layout:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is some very long text. This is some very long text. This is some very long text. This is some very long text. This is some very long text. "
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The two text views are placed together in a packed chain which will center the views. Setting the bias to "0.0" moves the text views all the way to the left of the screen. Setting `app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"` keeps the text views within the boundaries of the screen.

[image]